# Tracking what features are loaded

Tags: load, feature

Because I am loading various features for minibuffer completion (icomplete, ivy, vertico), I want to keep track on what features I have loaded.  One way would involve setting an array or a list, where each value can be either 0 (feature not loaded) or 1 (feature loaded).

```
(setq recorder [0 0 0])

Element 0     Icomplete loaded or not
Element 1     Ivy loaded or not
Element 2     Vertico loaded or not
```

What is easier to work with, a list or an array?

Comment: Please don't ask if XYZ is "a good idea". That encourages opinion-based answers and will likely get your question closed as a result. I removed that part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use function `featurep` to test whether some feature is present.
2. You can check the value of variable `load-history` to see which features have been loaded so far. Features have the form `(provide . FEATURE)` in the variable value, where `FEATURE` is the feature name.